# Error Using PHP for iPhone APNS

Tags: php, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, push-notification

I have been getting this error messages from my PHP code used to send message to the APNS...has anyone got faced the same issue?

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation 
failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:
SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in 
/Library/WebServer/Documents/anish/apns/2.php on line 8

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable 
crypto in /Library/WebServer/Documents/anish/apns/2.php on line 8

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect 
to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /Library/WebServer
/Documents/anish/apns/2.php on line 8
Failed to connect: 0

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in   
/Library/WebServer/Documents/anish/apns/2.php on line 20*
```

Also it seems it always fails to connect to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com. I even tried with PushMeBaby and it too fails to connect to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com

Answer (score 4):

the problem apparently was with the installation of certificates. If the certificate are installed properly, then everything works great like a charm..!

Comment: @Anish What have you done to fix your certificates installation ? My path to the certificate is correct.